# How to get a simple JQuery code working in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to use this on my site but it doesn't appear to work in IE.

http://jsfiddle.net/b43hj/24/

How can I get it to work in all browsers?

Thanks

edit -

I only have what's on the jsfiddle page. In Firefox and Opera, the div scrolls with the page content until it reaches its end, at which point it becomes fixed as the rest of the page continues scrolling. In IE8, the content appears under the div, not behind it. It works on the jsfiddle page but not on my own html page.

Here's what I'm testing: http://cornisharchive.site90.net/test/222.html

Comment: What are you expecting the code to do ?

Comment: How is it not working in IE?? Explain what the expected behavior is and what is the resultant behavior in IE.

Comment: Which version of IE? Those jsFiddles look identical in FF9, IE9 and Chrome 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

position:fixed is problematic in older versions of IE as well as when your page is using the wrong DOCTYPE.

Try using this as the first line in your HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Here is a link that talks about problems/solution with position:fixed in IE: http://tagsoup.com/cookbook/css/fixed/

Answer (score 0):

Place the following link in your head as your first script call:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1/CFInstall.min.js"></script>
```

It's a small simple online js that will check if its an IE browser, if it is, it will show a popup-like dialog forwarding the user to install "ChromeFrame" which makes IE run like chome, full jquery and css3 support!!!

Comment: Don't really want my website's users to have to install anything

Comment: Was just a suggestion and makes it to where you no longer have to write 2 sperate packs of code, otherwise, to make it fully functional to everyone you'll still have to write specific code for ie and general code for everyone else.  Keep in mind IE is now one of the LEAST used browsers online (when compared to chrome and ff which have much better js and css support) http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp